# How do I convert my screenshot to binary?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, type-conversion

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project in which I want to transform my screenshot which is .PNG, to binary and upload it to a server.

Now the server part requires an API which I will be handed over by someone who has already made it, and I will only have to implement it... after I complete this task

I have so far succeeded in taking a screenshot of the whole screen and saving it into my device, so, I only need a bit of help with the Conversion part.. I have found a code for a solution but due to lack of knowledge and experience in C# I failed to implement it...

This is MainPage.xaml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UploadingFiles.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Document filled"                          
        FontSize="12.5"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        FontFamily="MYICON"
        BorderColor="Black"
        Padding="0,0,0,0"
        BorderWidth="1"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        WidthRequest="120"
        HeightRequest="23"
        CornerRadius="0"
        Clicked="DoPDFThings"
        TextColor="Black"
        FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the C# part...

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NativeMedia;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace UploadingFiles
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void DoPDFThings(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync(); //    working 100% for partial sc: was var imageStream = await header.CaptureImageAsync();

            //  working 100% for partial sc: await MediaGallery.SaveAsync(MediaFileType.Image, imageStream, "myScreenshot.png");

            //  var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();

            await MediaGallery.SaveAsync(MediaFileType.Image, await screenshot.OpenReadAsync(), "myScreenshot.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a PNG file *is* a binary file. Can you do a File.ReadAllBytes on that file, or save it to a MemoryStream instead?

Comment: I was told to ' just read the file into a byte array '

Comment: As you already have a `Stream` with the image data, it seems you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71655362/3181933

Comment: I got an error: "  extention method must be in a non generic static class "

Comment: Well, then define your extension method inside a non-generic static class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert the stream you have to MemoryStream and use the MemoryStream.ToArray method. Such as:

```
 var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync(); 
 var byte[] array;
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
    screenshot.CopyTo(ms);
    array = ms.ToArray();
 }
```

Or you want to get the array from a local file:

```
 byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("");//provide the path of the .PNG in the ("")
```

Comment: Will try this. just need to find the path of image in my native gallery

Comment: Has the problem been solved?@Charbel

Comment: still trying to find the path to my image, im very slow haha, when i do and it works I'll give u the Nike check

Comment: do u have any tips on finding the path? I set it to: " /Users/charbelmansour/.android/avd/tablet_m-dpi_10_1in_pie_9_0_-_api_28.avdsnapshots/default_boot/myScreenshot.png") " to no avail

Comment: You need to copy the file into the simulator, you can check the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344848/slash-xamarin-issue/72346345#72346345). @Charbel